# The Empty Relation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, terminology

In elementary set theory, a relation on sets $A,B$ is usually defined as a subset of $A\times B$. We know that there are $2^{|A\times B|}$ subsets of $|A\times B|$. One of these subsets is the empty set. Do we include the empty set as a relation on $A$ and $B$?

In other words, is the number of relations between two sets simply $2^{|A\times B|}$?

(Additionally, is 'the empty relation' the correct term for what I am describing?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the empty relation is a proper relation and useful. Think of the "does not love"-relation on $\{$Romeo,Juliet$\}$.

Comment: Do they love themselves?

Comment: @Berci Maybe not that passionately.

Comment: Or consider the relation $\sim$ where $a\sim b$ means $|a-b| = \frac12$. Then for example $1\not\sim2; 1\sim\frac32; \frac32\sim 2$. But the restriction of this relation to the positive integers is empty; we have $p\not\sim q$ for every pair of positive integers.